# Twitter Search Widget

Tags: twitter

I can only seem to get the twitter search widget to display the most recent three tweets. Can this be extended? How far back in time does the widget retrieve information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that there are only three tweets showing, because the default is `30` in the widget as I know, except if there are only three tweets related to the search term!

However, you can add whatever optional properties you want to the widget, see all with details [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). For going back in time I think `since_id` and `until` are going to interest you.

If you want to determine the number of tweets to show, you should use the `rpp` property, which can have a max value 0f `100`, this is an example:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: 'rainbow',
  interval: 30000,
  rpp: 50,                   // WE ARE HERE IN THE VERY BODY OF THE OBJECT!
  title: 'It\'s a double rainbow',
  subject: 'Across the sky',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8ec1da',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#1985b5'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

Hope that's useful!